# How to do Map in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for data structure that is supposed to do the following.

I have a map like this:

```
public class Cls{ }

public class Container {
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private Map<Int, Cls> m = // What?;

    public void accept(Integer i, Cls c){
       m.put(i, c);
    }
}
```

I need to maintain difference between the smallest and the largest key `<= THRESHOLD` in the map `m`.

In case of `TreeMap` and manual deletion I will end up with logarithmic delete and search complexity.

Is there something faster maybe in `Commons` or `Guava`? Or maybe it's easy to do manually?

Comment: So you want to access the smallest and largest Integer keys quickly?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes

Comment: @JamesKPolk Maybe constant time... I'm pretty much sure that deleting smallest/largest and inserting something else can be done very fast...

Comment: Those are pretty unique requirements, much weaker than SortedMap. I would think you could implement your own Map to do this pretty easily.

Comment: What about a dequeue, where you keep in first position the smallest element and the biggest element in last position? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Comment: Have a look into [Brownies Collections](http://www.magicwerk.org/page-collections-overview.html), the key collections may help you.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you allow deletions then it becomes more complicated. I think you'd want something like a heap (priority queue). Guava has a [MinMaxPriorityQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html) that you might be able to use to do the heavy lifting behind a custom Map implementation.